Linking LuaJIT or other prebuilt static C libraries with Premake5
I'm writing a game using Raylib with the help of Premake5. I used a template to get started, specifically this one; https://github.com/raylib-extras/game-premake.
I can't seem to figure out how to just link a set .lib. The reason I require this is that LuaJIT is very difficult to embed. With standard lua, I just put the source files into a folder, used the provided premake5.lua and everything builds as expected.
I used the template library premake5.lua, just edited to try to link to the specific library (LuaJIT also created 5 files, minilua.lib, buildvm.lib, luajit.lib, lua51.lib and lua51.dll, so I wasn't sure which one to use from the onset). This was what I'd tried:
baseName = path.getbasename(os.getcwd());

project (baseName)
    kind "StaticLib"
    location "../_build/%{os.target()}"
    targetdir "../_bin/%{os.target()}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

    links { "%{os.getcwd()}/build/%{os.target()}/lua51" } -- also tried luajit
    
    -- and also tried the following:
    libdirs { "%{os.getcwd()}/build/%{os.target()}" }
    links { "lua51" --[[or "luajit"]] }

Though this seems to make the project to be treated as though it has source files. I attempted to circumvent Premake entirely via adding linkoptions { "../../lua/build/%{os.target()}/lua51.lib" } to the game's premake file directly, but the linker would still complain about undefined references to all Lua api functions. Here's an excerpt from the generated makefile;
ifeq ($(config),debug_x64)
TARGETDIR = ../../_bin/windows/Debug
TARGET = $(TARGETDIR)/project_unbound.exe
OBJDIR = obj/x64/Debug/project_unbound
DEFINES += -DDEBUG -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -DGRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33 -D_WIN32 -DGRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_43
ALL_CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -g -std=c99
ALL_CXXFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -g -std=c++17
LIBS += ../../_bin/windows/Debug/raylib.lib ../../_bin/windows/Debug/sqlite3.lib ../../_bin/windows/Debug/flecs.lib -lwinmm -lkernel32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
LDDEPS += ../../_bin/windows/Debug/raylib.lib ../../_bin/windows/Debug/sqlite3.lib ../../_bin/windows/Debug/flecs.lib

##### the above mentioned "workaround" causes the path to be added here, instead of above with the rest of the linked libraries
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS) -L../../_bin/windows/Debug -L/usr/lib64 -m64 ../../lua/build/windows/lua51.dll 

Following DirectX12 with Premake5: Linking Directx12 Static Libraries, the linker errors: 'C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llua51: No such file or directory'
I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

given how few hits there seem to be when I google for "premake getcwd" I would suggest hard coding the full path in the "libdirs" section to see if it works any better, i.e. libdirs { "/my/full/path/lua/build" } and then links { "lua51" }

Interestingly enough, when giving the full absolute path to the directory, it does actually attempt to load the library, but both the .lib and the .dll are skipped due to being "incompatible".
Since I just followed the luajit build instructions without too much thought, could it be a bitness problem?
edit: Just checked, luajit seems to build x86 on windows by default...

After coercing the visual studio command line to build for x64, I was able to get everything running. As expected, it was something obvious that I simply missed, thank you

The solution was indeed to use libdirs { "path/to/lib" } and links { "libname" }, though variables in the path were causing issues. setting the path as a fixed string fixed everything.
